# Need a regulear expression to be used with preg_replace() in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

I intend to replace all the strings starting as style=" having anything in-between and ending with " . Am trying to use this call but it isn't working:

```
preg_replace('/style="*"/', '', $feed[$x]['desc']);
```

It is replacing only style=" and leaving the rest intact e.g. for style="border:1px solid red" am still getting border:1px solid red" after the replacement, which means that the * wildcard is wrong to be used here. 
How can I indicate that there can be anything in-between "" then ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you obviously want everything except a quote character, so use `/style="[^"]*"/`

in regexes, the asterisk means "0 or more repetitions of the previous character"

Answer (score 0):

in your pattern the wildcars is for the `"` You should use `".*?"` or something like this